# How do you specify the bfloat16 mixed precision with the Intel Extension for PyTorch?

Tags: machine-learning, intel-pytorch, intel-ai-analytics

I would like to know how to use mixed precision with PyTorch and Intel Extension for PyTorch.

I have tried to look at the documentation on their GitHub, but I can't find anything that specifies how to go from fp32 to blfoat16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IPEX GitHub might not be the best place to look for API documentation. I would try and use the [PyTorch IPEX page](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/intel_extension_for_pytorch.html), which includes examples of API applications.

This would be an example of how to use fp32

`model, optimizer = ipex.optimize(model, optimizer, dtype=torch.float32)`

This would be an example of how to use bfloat16

`model, optimizer = ipex.optimize(model, optimizer, dtype=torch.bfloat16)`